# Misunderstanding of cypher query in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Look at following example graph (from Neo4j reference):

[image]

And ther query is:

```
MATCH (david { name: 'David' })--(otherPerson)-->()
WITH otherPerson, count(*) AS foaf
WHERE foaf > 1
RETURN otherPerson.name
```

The result is:

```
"Anders"
```

I can't understand why this result was returnes. First of all,
what does it mean:

```
MATCH (david { name: 'David' })--(otherPerson)-->()
WITH otherPerson, count(*) AS foaf
```

In particualr, `Bossman` has also (like `Anders`) two outgoing edges and is connected to `David`.

Can someone explain me a semantic of this query ?

Answer (score 3):

So as you noted there are two nodes which look like they fit the pattern you described. Both Anders and Bossman are connected to David, and both have two outgoing relationships.

The thing you're missing is that with Cypher patterns, [relationships are unique for the pattern](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/introduction/uniqueness/#cypherdoc-uniqueness), they will not be reused (this is actually very useful, for example it prevents infinite loops when using variable-length relationships when a cycle is present).

So in this MATCH pattern:

```
MATCH (david { name: 'David' })--(otherPerson)-->()
```

the relationship used to get from David to Bossman (the :BLOCKS relationship) will not be reused in the pattern (specifically the `(otherPerson)-->()` part), so you will only get a single result row for this, while for Anders you will get 2. Your WHERE clause then rules out the match for Bossman, since the count of `foaf` is 1.

One way you could alter this query to get the desired result is to check for the degrees of a relationship in the WHERE clause rather than in the MATCH pattern. This is also more efficient as checking for relationship degrees doesn't have to perform an expand operation, the relationship degree data is on the node itself.

```
MATCH ({ name: 'David' })--(otherPerson)
WHERE size((otherPerson)-->()) > 1
RETURN otherPerson.name
```

(also it's a good idea to use node labels in your matches, at least for your intended starting nodes. Indexes (if present) will only be used when you explicitly use both the label and the indexed property in the match, it won't work when you omit the label, or use a label that's not a part of the index).